# Is my PHP form secure?

Tags: php, forms, security, email, sanitize

I have a form and this bit of code to send it:

```
if($feedback != $errorMessage){
$emailTo = 'me@mywebsite.com';
$emailFrom = 'submissions@mywebsite.com';
$subject = 'Submission';
$body = filter_var("$contactName made a submission.

    Contact Information:
    Contact Name:\t$contactName
    blah:\t$blah
    Address:\t$address
    Telephone:\t$telephone
    Mobile:\t$mobile
    E-mail Address:\t$userEmail
    Website:\t$website

    Vacancy Information:
    field1:\t$field1
    field2 Benefits:\t$field2
    field3:\t$field3
    field4:\t$field4
    field5:\t$field5
    field6:\t$field6
    field7:\t$field7
    field8:\t$field8
    field9:\t$field9", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
mail($emailTo, $subject, $body, "From: ".$emailFrom);
}
```

From what I understand from reading other threads this should be enough.  I tried emailing just a single dot on a line in one of the textareas and it did turn it into 2 dots.  Just running one function on it seems far too simple though.

Is this secure enough?  I've read things online that seem inconsistent like that I don't even have to sanitize the body.  The email body is the only thing that takes user input here.

Thanks.

Comment: raw concatenation of strings emailed -> inherently insecure.

Comment: Why not trash `mail()` and use PHPMailer of SwiftMailer instead?

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what you mean by secure here. Your script is just sending an email. The content of the fields will be what the user filled in. It could be link to virus, crap, spam or real content. Not easy to say, really. Not much to do with it either.

Sanitizing is much more important once databases are in use.

Comment: I think the OP is asking if their `filter_var` "validation" is good enough to prevent any kind of attacks.

Comment: @AmalMurali - What kind of attacks? What can you really do in a mail body?